# Getting values of multiple selected column data from ListView

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, listview

I am writing a simple wpf window that binds sql data to `ListView` tables. It's easier to explain this on code, so here is my XAML:

```
<ListView Name="listViewItem" ClipToBounds="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="ListView_SizeChanged" Loaded="ListView_Loaded" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" Margin="0,0,83,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company Name" Width="150">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company Address" Width="350">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyAddress}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The Companyname and CompanyAddress binding is done in code behind :

```
private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CompanyName, CompanyAddress FROM Groups", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Groups");
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        listViewItem.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

My goal was to get data from specific selected columns, and so far I have come to this :

```
var selectedItem = listViewItem.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
if(selectedItem != null)
{
    string name = selectedItem["CompanyName"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

with the help of mm8. But now, this only allows me to get one value form one selected row. What if I'd like to iterate through all the selected columns? I tried using `listViewItem.SelectedItems` as `DataRowView`, but I wasn't able to assign both the column name and the current iteration id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach(var selectedItem in listViewItem.SelectedItems.OfType<DataRowView>())
{
    string name = selectedItem["CompanyName"].ToString();
}
```